Ошибка при тестировании nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
приложение на spring boot 2.77 и kotlin
в коде используется библиотека для работы и сохранения объектов в jsonb
entity
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinition
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "route")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
class RoutEntity(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: String,

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", name = "event_data", nullable = false)
    var eventData: Route
)

зависимости для работы с БД и сущностями.
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55:3.7.0")
implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0")
implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.19.0")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

Ошибка появляется когда подключаю тесты.
Если тесты убрать - сборка проходит и локально сервис тестируется.
когда тесты подключаю то возвращается ошибка
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement

или такая
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType"

как если бы зависимости для io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType не было для тестов.
Но этот класс содержится в зависимости implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55:3.7.0") не понятно как такое пофиксить.
